# Why is ValueError not raised?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Python documentation states :

[image]

so my code is:

```
print(pow(-2,2.1))
```

this code should raise ValueError, as -2 and 2 are finite, -2 is negative, and 2.1 is not an integer - hence pow(-2,2.1) is undefined.

Comment: You used `pow`, not `math.pow`.

Comment: For that to happen, use `from math import pow` and then `print(pow(-2,2.1))`

Comment: It does raise `ValueErrow: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power`.

Comment: @Ry- I got the answer, how do I close this question here?

Comment: there is no point in closing the question. What you can do though, is accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the built-in `pow` function with the documentation for `math.pow`

See here for the built-in `pow` function:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow

> Return x to the power y; if z is present, return x to the power y,
>   modulo z (computed more efficiently than pow(x, y) % z). The
>   two-argument form pow(x, y) is equivalent to using the power operator:
>   x**y.
>
> The arguments must have numeric types. With mixed operand types, the
>   coercion rules for binary arithmetic operators apply. For int
>   operands, the result has the same type as the operands (after
>   coercion) unless the second argument is negative; in that case, all
>   arguments are converted to float and a float result is delivered. For
>   example, 10**2 returns 100, but 10**-2 returns 0.01. If the second
>   argument is negative, the third argument must be omitted. If z is
>   present, x and y must be of integer types, and y must be non-negative.

It's also worth noting that the result from the built-in `pow` function is the same as using `**` ie 
`pow(-2,2.1)` is equivalent to `(-2) ** 2.1`